# Visual Basic Excel For Loop In Multiple Cells How To Use The Counter In The Range("")

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

This is what I have, so the H needs to be followed by the number of the cell, I want to use the counter i here, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? :)

```
For i = 60 To 63

    Range("Hi").AddComment
    Range("Hi").Comment.Visible = False
    Range("Hi").Comment.Text Text:=""
    i = i + 1
    Range("Hi").Select
    i = i - 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Range("H" & i)
```

As you wrote it, `"Hi"` does not use the variable i because you put it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this instead:

```
For i = 60 To 63

    Range("H" & i).AddComment
    Range("H" & i).Comment.Visible = False
    Range("H" & i).Comment.Text Text:=""
    i = i + 1
    Range("H" & i).Select
    i = i - 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The `&` operator does concatenation in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You should format it like this:

```
    For i = 60 To 63

        Range("H" & i).AddComment
        Range("H" & i).Comment.Visible = False
        Range("H" & i).Comment.Text Text:=""
        i = i + 1
        Range("H" & i).Select
        i = i - 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

The reason is that the letter `H` is a character and `i` is a variable. anything inside of double quotes `"Hi"` like that Excel will read as just a string of text.

When Excel reads a word or letter outside of quotes `i` it will assume it is a variable. The `&` character joins the two together as text.

This means that each time the loop runs Excel will read it as `"H" and i` and translate it to "H1", "H2", "H3", .... "H60" and input it into the `Range()` like you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work better for you? I've always had issues when the value of i starts chaging inside the loop code

```
For i = 60 To 63      
    With Range("H" & i)
        .Select 
        .AddComment     
        .Comment.Visible = False     
        .Comment.Text Text:=""  
    end with
Next 
End Sub
```